# Regex pattern to split string

Tags: java, regex, split

Tried to split and find out what regex pattern can be done for my case , but didn't find solution.
I have following string

```
param1=234&param2=5||param3>3&param4=N/A (04)&param5=some valued&param6=this good - new value&param7=A (newparam)
```

My steps

```
1. string.replaceAll("&|\\|\\|", ",");
2. string.split("[\\w,]")
```

if put such string

```
param1=234&param2=5||param3>3
```

then it split up to to values:

```
param1
234
param2
5
param3
3
```

But when i have whitespaces and "/" and "("  and "-" then it's divided to each value.
What a regex pattern should be used then in order to get following output?

```
param1
234
param2
5
param3
3
param4
N/A (04)
param5
some valued
param6
this good - new value
param7
A (newparam)
```

I do it for inserting them after this as key=value into map. May be other way exists to approach but for now if i have separated array of values then i can insert them into a map.

So, for now I need only a regex how to split it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Split on `[=&>]|\\|\\|`

Comment: Use `s.split("\\|{2}|[&=<>]")`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wCMHE0/1).

Comment: Wow gus i tried to resolve for about to find out what pattern and you wrote here the answer. I need to learn  this regex from the beginning. And your answers should be in main answers. Need to vote for you guys. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Both of answers are good!! you saved me guys!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply this regex in your `.split()`

```
[=&>]|\\|\\|
```

- `[=&>]` - find an equal sign or ampersand or >
- `|` - or
- `\\|\\|` - find double pipes

`[=&>]` is equivalent to `=|&|>` so you could also use `=|&|>|\\|\\|` if it's more legible to you.

Comment: And what about if i want to add also >=  -- equal or greater?
`param1=234&param2=5||param3>3param4>=5`

Comment: @master17 since it's two consecutive chars then add it with a pipe at the end like `|>=`. Ditto for `|<=`. If you're just adding an individual char then you can throw it inside of the char set braces `[]`

Comment: you mean like this :
`[=&><]||\|\||<=|>=`

Comment: no its not working for expression with >= and <=

Comment: @master17 I took a better look at `[=&><]||\|\||<=|>=` and it looks wrong. For java you need to escape the escape `\\|`. Not sure why you made that mistake...

Comment: yes i know that i need to escape it but can't find where it should be located 
i tried some ways and doesn't return me the needed output
`[=&><]|\\|\\|\\|>=\\|>=`

Can you please just write out here the final regex?

Comment: It's good
`[=&]|\|\||<=|>=` but it doesn't take into account > or < 
And when i add single < and > then >= doesn't work

Comment: Found that is the answer : works perfect
`[=&]|\\|\\||<=|>=|>|<`
I just extracted from brackets > and <
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a key-value mapping:

1. Split on `&|\|\|`, obtaining strings as `param1=234`, `param2=5` and `param3>3`.
2. For each string split on `[>=]` for obtaining the single key-value pair.